# Puzzling Bash syntax -- redirect into loop

Tags: bash, syntax, io-redirection

Running a script through shellcheck.net I was told that ["`for` loops over `find` output are fragile."](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2044) Fair enough, filenames with spaces are always tricky.

The suggested replacement code (one of them anyway) was this:

```
while IFS= read -r -d '' file
do
    #do stuff
done <   <(find . -name '*' -print0)
```

I'm familiar with the `<` operator used to input text from a file to a command, and clearly the results from `find` are being fed into the loop. So when I first saw this, I thought it was victim to some formatting problems and tried "cleaning up" the last line. But removing the whitespace between `< <` resulted in syntax errors, as did adding one into `<(`.

So what is the `< <(cmd)` construct doing? Apologies if this is a simple or redundant question, it's not easy to search for these things!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `<` is [input redirection](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Redirecting-Input) as you say.

The `<(` is [Process Substitution](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Process-Substitution).

> Process substitution is supported on systems that support named pipes (FIFOs) or the /dev/fd method of naming open files. It takes the form of
>
> ```
> <(list)
> ```
>
> or
>
> ```
> >(list)
> ```
>
> The process list is run with its input or output connected to a FIFO or some file in /dev/fd. The name of this file is passed as an argument to the current command as the result of the expansion. If the >(list) form is used, writing to the file will provide input for list. If the <(list) form is used, the file passed as an argument should be read to obtain the output of list. Note that no space may appear between the < or > and the left parenthesis, otherwise the construct would be interpreted as a redirection.
>
> When available, process substitution is performed simultaneously with parameter and variable expansion, command substitution, and arithmetic expansion.

You can't combine the two `<` marks because then that becomes a [here document](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html) token.

You can't add a space between `<` and `(` because then it stops being the process substitution token.

Comment: Got it; so the output from the command is sent to a file descriptor, and the `<(cmd)` statement is expanded into that file descriptor name. (And now I have a term to search for if I need any more info!)

Comment: Yup. See `echo <(echo foo)` and `cat <(echo foo)` for example.

Answer (score 3):

A `while` loop in `bash` is an example of a compound command. Like any other command, it has its own standard input. It doesn't actually read from it at all, but any command run from within the `while` loop will inherit its standard input from the loop.

In this example, the `read` command will read from the output of the `find` command.

---

`<(find ...)` is an example of *process substitution*. The `find` command is run, and the `<(...)` is treated like a file whose contents are the output of the `find` command. It is this "file" that the `while` loop (and therefore `read`) uses for its standard input.